# Django - ManyToMany relation without the cross table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 models: City and Service. Each city record can contain many services and each service can be linked to each city.

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class CityService(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    service = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
```

I use *ManyToManyField* to enable the multiple selections in Django admin.
But Django creates one more table to store m2m relations..

Is it possible to configure Django models so that to reach the following table structure:

```
+----+---------------+------------+
| id | city_id       | service_id |
+----+---------------+------------+
|  1 |             1 |         1  |
|  2 |             1 |         2  |
|  3 |             2 |         3  |
+----+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: If you want the model to be the way you have described it, then obviously there is no need for ManyToManyField.
But storing data this way is like adding redundant data to your database as you'll be creating a new object everytime to have a city and service mapping when instead you can simply store a list of services for a particular city which is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a structure like:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    service = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the CityService table at all. A ManyToManyField *already* implies a join table; you are creating a *second* one, to no purpose at all. Have the M2M directly between City and Service.

Answer (score 1):

you misunderstood the `ManyToManyField` usage.
You do not need to create a separate model to use this relation. To create a separate model to work as `ManyToManyField` relation is mentioned below. But doing so you will not able to use the feature that `Django` provides for this `manytomany` relation.

```
class CityService(models.Model):
  # Also you can add additional fields
  city = models.ForeignKey(City)
  service = models.ForeignKey(Service)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('city', 'service') # Make sure you dont have duplicate record in the table if so then remove this relation.
```

But if you like to go with the Django provided `ManyToManyField` relation and let them create one separate table. just use below code.. same is suggested by @Jedi already.

```
class City(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Service(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  city = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```